# Draw a simple line graph in Swing

Tags: java, swing, linegraph

How can i draw a line graph in  `Java Swing`. I'm making a program in which when user clicks on a jframe it will record its coordinate and when it click on a button named Draw Graph, it generates a line graph using the points. So, How can i draw a line graph in Swing

Comment: Override paintComponet method and use Graphics method to draw something on component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) to plot different kinds of graphs.

Comment: there are many libraries in this folder where to put this libraries, and how can i make use of it?

Comment: @user1167744 you need to add jars to the classpath. Then you can import the classes you need in your class and use it.

Comment: :can i draw it without adding any external libraries?

Comment: @user1167744 if you will be using JFreeChart then you will need it's jar files. Apart from it, I m not sure about any way to draw line graphs in Swings. You can do in Applets but in Swings, am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You could use http://gef.tigris.org/ gef library in order to represent your graphs.

Answer (score -1):

The IMHO easiest way is extending a JComponent and overwriting the related paintComponent(Graphics) method.

[EDIT] Inserted correct method name.

Comment: please be precise: XXX = Component

Comment: if you don't know the answer, simply ... don't answer :-)

Comment: I knew the answer but just was unsure about the correct paint method... thus I wrote "related paintXXX(Graphics)" in my original post.